# onTransitionEnd not working Android 4.3 Samsung S3

Tags: javascript, android, css, mobile-browser

I have a small nifty game I'm trying to develop at [this link](http://www.kendallarneaud.me/clients/mccann/crix) which has **css transition** class definitions

```
`el {
transition: transform .3s;
-webkit-transition: -webkit-transform .3s;
position:absolute; 
transform: translate3d(0,-100%,0);
-webkit-transform: translate3d(0,-100%,0);
top:0;
}
.close {
transition-duration: .15s;
-webkit-transition-duration: .15s;
}
.open {
transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
-webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
}`
```

on elements and uses a *[prefix]TransitionEnd* event to function.

```
$el.on(transitionEnd,function(){ // transitionEnd is a polyfill result from browser sniff
if($el.hasClass('close'))
setTimeout(function(){
  $el.addClass('open');
},Math.random() * 2500));
else $el.addClass('close').removeClass('open');
});
```

The expected result is that the function would change the element's translate3d() based on the class add/removed each time the transition ends.

I am able to see this in action on desktop and mobile browsers **except for the Samsung Galaxy S3 running Android 4.3**. I was told that on the S3 that it runs only once and the elements remain with the ".close" class. I don't have an actual device but the little debugging I did is leading me to believe that the *[prefix]TransitionEnd* is not firing when changing the class definitions which affects the transitions. Can anyone with a **Samsung S3 with Android 4.3** try it out and let me know if it works...and what workaround I can use to solve it?

Comment: Having the same issue, thought it was just me. If i find a solution I'll let you know.

Comment: @Justin cool i think i have found a solution. Gonna try it and let you know

Comment: @easwee I made some edits. Hopes this suffice with the house rules :-)

Comment: @Justin I took some advice from this article http://blog.alexmaccaw.com/css-transitions. Test using http://developer.samsung.com/home.do Samsung emulators reveal that it works however, I'm yet to confirm on an actual device

Comment: Cool, let me know what you find. I ended up just firing a setTimeout for the same milliseconds my css transition was set for, basically doing the same thing. Its not ideal and is a bit hacky but works like a charm.